# Adding a config file to my JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, config, configuration-files

I have a JavaScript project that includes both frontend and backend codes (NodeJS). This is my production folder structure:

```
/prod
    /server
        sourceCode1.js
        sourceCode2.js
        ...
        sourceCodeN.js
        index.js
    /client
        bundle.js
    ReadMe.md
    license.txt
```

When user hit my `/server/index.js`, I call `express.static(__dirname + '/../client')` to serve user js files in `/client` folder.
I have plenty of frontend js files under `/client` folder originally, but they are minified and combined into one `bundle.js` when they are moved to `prod` as you can see above. I want to add one single config file in JSON format that contains configuration for both my backend and frontend code. But I'm not sure where/how to place it. I think no matter where I put it, my code in `/server/index.js` can access it with no problem. But for `/client/bundle.js`, accessing the config file will require another request to the server which seems poor design to me...

Can anyone suggest a way that solves the problem better?

P.S.

I use `gulp` to minify and combine my frontend js files into `bundle.js`, I can put the config file in `/client` folder and use `gulp` to bundle it together with other js files as well. But that means every time I change the config file, I need to `gulp` everything again which doesn't make any sense.

PPS.
I agree pulp will work just fine for myself. Another reason I didn't want to use pulp to bundle the config file is that this is an open source project, I'm hoping when someone else uses it and he only wants to change one tiny setting in the config file, he doesn't have to go through the `gulp` step..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can put the config file in `/client` folder and use gulp to bundle it together with other js files as well. But that means every time I change the config file, I need to gulp everything again which doesn't make any sense.

I think it **does** make sense. [Other people do too](https://github.com/ajwhite/gulp-ng-config).

If you're worried about speed, I recommend having two Gulp tasks: **`Dev`** and **`Build`**.

- **`Dev`** should watch the source for changes and update the configuration.
- **`Build`** should do slow things like bundling and minification *as well* as update the configuration.

Comment: Right, I agree `pulp` will work just fine for myself. Another reason I didn't want to use `pulp` to bundle the config file is that this is an open source project, I'm hoping when someone else uses it and he only wants to change a setting in the config file, he doesn't have to go through the `gulp` process...